# FastAPI w/ TortoiseORM: Error: Unprocessable Entity

Tags: python, python-3.x, fastapi, tortoise-orm

I'm new to fastAPI and trying to build a todo API. I use Tortoise-ORM. I believe the error was caused by entering null value to the todo section although i want it to be null or set to default value which is an empty list. This is the code related to the error.
**main.py**

```
from typing import List
import os

from fastapi import FastAPI, Depends, HTTPException, status

from models import User, Todo, User_pydantic, UserIn_pydantic, Todo_pydantic, TodoIn_pydantic
from tortoise.contrib.fastapi import register_tortoise, HTTPNotFoundError

app = FastAPI()

@app.post("/users/", response_model=User_pydantic)
async def create_user(user: UserIn_pydantic):
    user_obj = await User.create(**user.dict(exclude_unset=True))
    return await User_pydantic.from_tortoise_orm(user_obj)


@app.get("/users/", response_model=List[User_pydantic])
async def read_all_users():
    return await User_pydantic.from_queryset(User.all())
```

**models.py**

```
from tortoise.models import Model
from tortoise import fields
from tortoise.contrib.pydantic import pydantic_model_creator


class Todo(Model):
    id = fields.IntField(pk=True)
    title = fields.CharField(500)
    description = fields.TextField(null=True)

Todo_pydantic = pydantic_model_creator(Todo, name="Todo")
TodoIn_pydantic = pydantic_model_creator(Todo, name="TodoIn", exclude_readonly=True)

class User(Model):
    id = fields.IntField(pk=True)
    username = fields.CharField(500, unique=True)
    email = fields.CharField(100, unique=True)
    password = fields.CharField(100)
    is_active = fields.BooleanField(default=True)
    todo: fields.ForeignKeyNullableRelation[Todo] = fields.ForeignKeyField("models.Todo", related_name="todo")

    class PydanticMeta:
        exclude = ["is_active", "todo"]

User_pydantic = pydantic_model_creator(User, name="User")
UserIn_pydantic = pydantic_model_creator(User, name="UserIn", exclude_readonly=True)
```

The error began when i tried to create a new user. Here is the error from swagger UI

```
{
  "detail": [
    {
      "loc": [],
      "msg": "null value in column \"todo_id\" of relation \"user\" violates not-null constraint\nDETAIL:  Failing row contains (6, bob, bob@email.com, bob123, t, null).",
      "type": "IntegrityError"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is stated in the error

> "null value in column "todo_id" of relation "user" violates
> not-null constraint\nDETAIL:  Failing row contains (6, bob,
> bob@email.com, bob123, t, null).

I don't see any `todo_id` column in your `User` table, but I guess that it's just due to an issue with copying and pasting on SO.

I haven't used TortoiseORM (but I would like to once it reaches a stable release), but have you tried changing the definition of todo into the following?

```
todo: fields.ForeignKeyNullableRelation[Todo, None] = fields.ForeignKeyField("models.Todo", related_name="todo")
```

This way you are telling that the field is of type `ForeignKeyNullableRelation`, and either `Todo` or `None`.

That's my guess, too long to fit in the comments, so I posted it as an answer.

Let me know if it works or not.

Comment: @Isabi unfortunately your code didn't work. Here is the error i get
`TypeError(f"Too {'many' if alen > elen else 'few'} parameters for {cls};"
TypeError: Too many parameters for typing.Union[typing.Awaitable[typing.Union[~MODEL, NoneType]], ~MODEL, NoneType]; actual 2, expected 1`
It only expect 1 parameter

Comment: I don't know why the todo column doesn't appear. Not to mention TortoiseORM documentation for FastAPI only show simple models without any relation fields e.g. ForeignKeyField.

Comment: And what about todo: fields.ForeignKeyNullableRelation[Todo] = fields.ForeignKeyField("models.Todo", related_name="todo", null=True) ?

Comment: @Isabi i already tried that. The result is still the same

Comment: That's so strange. Try opening an issue on the github's repo and let me know

Comment: I never open a github issue before, but i'll do it later

Comment: It's not difficult. Just explain the problem as in SO. Of course there may be a template, follow it, but the more you specify the problem, the more people will be able to help

Comment: I already opened an issue. Here is the [link](https://github.com/tortoise/tortoise-orm/issues/523) if you want to check it out.

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue and found solution for that. Problem here is that your POST request is missing `todo_id` (not `todo` because database is automatically adding `_id` to relating fields). But if you try to add it you will get `extra fields not permitted`.
The reason for that is because `UserIn_pydantic` don't have this field. To solve it, first try to initialize your models by calling [init_models](https://tortoise-orm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setup.html?highlight=init_models#tortoise.Tortoise.init_models) something like this:

`Tortoise.init_models(['path_to_file_with_models'], 'models')`

after `pydantic_model_creator` should do the rest and it will work for most cases. if not then just simply override it:

```
UserIn_pydantic = pydantic_model_creator(User, name="UserIn", exclude_readonly=True)

class UsersIn_PydanticWithRelation(UsersIn_Pydantic):
    todo_id: int

User_pydantic = pydantic_model_creator(User, name="User")
class Users_PydanticWithRelation(Users_Pydantic):
   client_id: int
```

and in your **main.py** replace your types annotations. This way you will be abble to POST `todo_id`, it will be stored in database and you will be abble to return it.

At least this worked for me. I hope it will help you too. Let me know if it helps.